# pandas: how to run a pivot with a multi-index?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, multi-index

I would like to run a pivot on a pandas `DataFrame`, with the index being two columns, not one. For example, one field for the year, one for the month, an 'item' field which shows 'item 1' and 'item 2' and a 'value' field with numerical values. I want the index to be year + month.

The only way I managed to get this to work was to combine the two fields into one, then separate them again. is there a better way?

Minimal code copied below. Thanks a lot!

PS Yes, I am aware there are other questions with the keywords 'pivot' and 'multi-index', but I did not understand if/how they can help me with this question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame()
month = np.arange(1, 13)
values1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 12)
values2 = np.random.randint(200, 300, 12)


df['month'] = np.hstack((month, month))
df['year'] = 2004
df['value'] = np.hstack((values1, values2))
df['item'] = np.hstack((np.repeat('item 1', 12), np.repeat('item 2', 12)))

# This doesn't work: 
# ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 24, placement implies 2
# mypiv = df.pivot(['year', 'month'], 'item', 'value')

# This doesn't work, either:
# df.set_index(['year', 'month'], inplace=True)
# ValueError: cannot label index with a null key
# mypiv = df.pivot(columns='item', values='value')

# This below works but is not ideal: 
# I have to first concatenate then separate the fields I need
df['new field'] = df['year'] * 100 + df['month']

mypiv = df.pivot('new field', 'item', 'value').reset_index()
mypiv['year'] = mypiv['new field'].apply( lambda x: int(x) / 100)  
mypiv['month'] = mypiv['new field'] % 100
```

Comment: I've provided several detailed examples and alternative approaches in this  [**Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/2336654)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can group and then unstack.

```
>>> df.groupby(['year', 'month', 'item'])['value'].sum().unstack('item')
item        item 1  item 2
year month                
2004 1          33     250
     2          44     224
     3          41     268
     4          29     232
     5          57     252
     6          61     255
     7          28     254
     8          15     229
     9          29     258
     10         49     207
     11         36     254
     12         23     209
```

Or use `pivot_table`:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(
        values='value', 
        index=['year', 'month'], 
        columns='item', 
        aggfunc=np.sum)
item        item 1  item 2
year month                
2004 1          33     250
     2          44     224
     3          41     268
     4          29     232
     5          57     252
     6          61     255
     7          28     254
     8          15     229
     9          29     258
     10         49     207
     11         36     254
     12         23     209
```

Comment: @Alexander, `pivot_table()` requires _aggfunc_ parameter and if no such parameter is provided then `mean()` function is used by default. If `sum()` capability is required then `pivot_table()` function should have `aggfunc=sum` added to the call. 
    **Source:** 
[pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)
_aggfunc : function, list of functions, dict, default numpy.mean_

Comment: @rp1 Good point.  It was identical because the original sample dataframe only had one value per item, year and month.  Amending response to reflect correction.

Answer (score 34):

I believe if you include `item` in your MultiIndex, then you can just unstack:

```
df.set_index(['year', 'month', 'item']).unstack(level=-1)
```

This yields:

```
                value      
item       item 1 item 2
year month              
2004 1         21    277
     2         43    244
     3         12    262
     4         80    201
     5         22    287
     6         52    284
     7         90    249
     8         14    229
     9         52    205
     10        76    207
     11        88    259
     12        90    200
```

It's a bit faster than using `pivot_table`, and about the same speed or slightly slower than using `groupby`.

Comment: You can also reference the index level directly, e.g. df.set_index(['year', 'month', 'item']).unstack('fcode').  Alexander's first method in his answer would also fail with non-numerical data (in a more generalized problem than the one here).

Comment: this is an amazing answer.

Comment: I like this answer, but I'm having some trouble with its implementation. I have multiple columns of data, that I want to flatten to a single row. This answer gets me most of where I need to go, but I'm getting a ton of NaN's in my data. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I went with code like this: `df = pd.DataFrame(df.set_index(['PRS 3']).unstack(-1))` and then `df = df.transpose()`.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me:

```
mypiv = df.pivot(index=['year','month'],columns='item')[['values1','values2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to gmoutso [comment](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23955#issuecomment-497388903) you can use this:

```
def multiindex_pivot(df, index=None, columns=None, values=None):
    if index is None:
        names = list(df.index.names)
        df = df.reset_index()
    else:
        names = index
    list_index = df[names].values
    tuples_index = [tuple(i) for i in list_index] # hashable
    df = df.assign(tuples_index=tuples_index)
    df = df.pivot(index="tuples_index", columns=columns, values=values)
    tuples_index = df.index  # reduced
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples_index, names=names)
    df.index = index
    return df
```

usage:

```
df.pipe(multiindex_pivot, index=['idx_column1', 'idx_column2'], columns='foo', values='bar')
```

You might want to have a simple flat column structure and have columns to be of their intended type, simply add this:

```
(df
   .infer_objects()  # coerce to the intended column type
   .rename_axis(None, axis=1))  # flatten column headers
```