# How to group data frame with similar text in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame DF like this:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'def'],  
               'Description':['ABC String', 'ABC String', 'ABC String and sth', 'Only sth else', 'ABC String'],     
               'Value':[10, 20, 30, 40, 100]})
```

[image]

I need to group it by Code and Description. Grouping by Code is simple:

```
GR = DF.groupby('Code')
```

[image]

Now I want to continue with grouping by Description, so all values that are equal or similar (have a common part) are grouped together. Can you help me with a formula to get something like this:

[image]

It might be there are two questions: 'equal values' and 'similar values'. If there is any hint on at least the 'equal values', that would be great.

Comment: for the 'equal values' have you tried pivot table like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414625/pandas-how-to-run-a-pivot-with-a-multi-index)?

Comment: Are there many other "equal" strings? Other than ```ABC String```?

Comment: Thank you Amri, I will have a look.
Yes Serge, there are other strings in the original sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check for similar strings you can use jellyfish.levenshtein_distance.
Idea is to iterate over each group and grab the most frequent element from the group, then evaluate the levenshtein_distance relative to that most frequent element. If the distance is close to 0 that means the given string is similar and vice-versa.

```
# from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from statistics import mode
import jellyfish

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Code': ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'def'],
                   'Description': ['ABC String', 'abc string', 'ABC String and sth', 'Only sth else', 'ABC String'],
                   'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 100]})

df_list = []
for grp,df in df.groupby('Code'):
    df['distance'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x : jellyfish.levenshtein_distance(x, mode(df['Description'])))
    df['Description'] =  mode(df['Description'])
    df_list.append(df[df['distance'] < 10])

df = pd.concat(df_list).drop('distance', axis=1)
print(df)
```

**output -**

```
  Code Description  Value
0  abc  ABC String     10
1  abc  ABC String     20
2  abc  ABC String     30
4  def  ABC String    100
```

For more better and accurate analysis - convert the string to lower case remove spaces and punctuation and then follow the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Nk03. This is interesting approach which I will study more to accommodate to my final solution.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `fuzzywuzzy` to compute the Levensthein distance, even if there are more than two "similar" values

For example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

DF = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'def', 'def', 'def', 'abc'],  
               'Description':['ABC String', 'ABC String', 
                              'ABC String and sth', 'Only sth else', 
                              'ABC String', 'CDEFGH', 'CDEFGH and sth', 
                              'CDEFGH and sth',],
               'Value':[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]}) 

# for each unique value in Description
for d in DF.Description.unique():
    # compute Levensthein distance
    # and set to True if >= a limit
    # (you may have to play around with it)
    DF[d] = DF['Description'].apply(
        lambda x : fuzz.ratio(x, d) >= 60
    )
    # set a name for the group
    # here, simply the shortest
    m = np.min(DF[DF[d]==True].Description)
    # assign the group
    DF.loc[DF.Description==d, 'group'] = m

print(DF)

  Code         Description  Value  ABC String          group  \
0  abc          ABC String     10        True     ABC String   
1  abc          ABC String     20        True     ABC String   
2  abc  ABC String and sth     30        True     ABC String   
3  abc       Only sth else     40       False  Only sth else   
4  def          ABC String     50        True     ABC String   
5  def              CDEFGH     60       False         CDEFGH   
6  def      CDEFGH and sth     70       False         CDEFGH   
7  abc      CDEFGH and sth     80       False         CDEFGH   

   ABC String and sth  Only sth else  CDEFGH  CDEFGH and sth  
0                True          False   False           False  
1                True          False   False           False  
2                True          False   False           False  
3               False           True   False           False  
4                True          False   False           False  
5               False          False    True            True  
6               False          False    True            True  
7               False          False    True            True
```

And now you can `groupby` the created groups

```
DF.groupby('group').Value.mean()

group
ABC String       27.5
CDEFGH           70.0
Only sth else    40.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

this really depends on how you define similar....  if you say first 10 characters you can use string slicing.

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'def'],  
               'Description':['ABC String', 'ABC String', 'ABC String and sth', 'Only sth else', 'ABC String'],     
               'Value':[10, 20, 30, 40, 100]})  

DF.groupby(["Code", DF.Description.str[:10]])["Value"].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add boolean column with function and then apply:

```
val = 'ABC String'

df['boo'] = df['description'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x.find(val)>=0 else 0)
df
```

| code | description | value | boo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | ABC String | 10 | 1 |
| abc | ABC String | 20 | 1 |
| abc | ABC String and sth | 30 | 1 |
| abc | Only sth else | 40 | 0 |
| def | ABC String | 100 | 1 |

and then some wrangling

```
df = df[df.boo == 1]
df = df.iloc[:,:-1]
df
```

| code | description | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | ABC String | 10 |
| abc | ABC String | 20 |
| abc | ABC String and sth | 30 |
| def | ABC String | 100 |